# How many ways to choose $6$ numbers out of $\{1,2…,20\}$ such that there aren't two consecutive numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

I have seen a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067936/number-of-ways-to-choose-6-books-out-of-20-books-such-that-no-2-are-adjacent-boo) though I wasn't able to make the connection.

The answer is $\binom{15}{6}$ but I am not really sure on how to approach the question.
I understand that it uses "stars and bars", though as I said - not sure how.

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen stars and bars before?  Are you familiar with how to count the number of integral solutions to $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k = n\\x_i\geq 0~~~\forall i\end{cases}$ as being $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814048/the-number-of-ways-of-choosing-3-distinct-numbers-from-first-15-natural-numb) from earlier today.

Comment: yes I have seen it, dont understand why  this is the solution though

Comment: Let your set be $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_6\}$ with $a_1<a_2<\dots<a_6$.  Consider defining $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_7$ as $x_1=a_1-1, x_2=a_2-a_1-2, x_3=a_3-a_2-2,\dots, x_6=a_6-a_5-2, x_7 = 20-a_6$.  Recognize that $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_7 = 20-11=9$ and that each $x_i\geq 0$.  Recognize the bijection between 7-tuples of non-negative integers $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_7)$ satisfying $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_7=9$ and subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,20\}$ of size six with no consecutive numbers.  The answer then, $\binom{9+7-1}{7-1}=\binom{15}{6}$

Comment: As for why "this" being $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ "is the solution" to the problem of counting answers to $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k=n\\x_i\geq 0~~\forall i\end{cases}$, that is covered [on the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and elsewhere on this site.

Comment: but why would you take x1 to x7 ? you only need 6 numbers... that's my confusion

Comment: Because to describe those *six* numbers in your subset, I can do so by describing the *seven* regions to the left, between, or to the right of said numbers.  [Fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).  I *could* have gotten away with only using six values, but then that leaves me with $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_6$ merely being *at most* $9$ rather than necessarily *equal* to $9$ like is preferred to get it into the standard form for stars-and-bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the $6$ chosen numbers as the bars in the stars and bars model; the remaining $14$ numbers are the stars, and they have to be distributed in the $7$ spaces defined by the $6$ bars. There must be at least one star between any two adjacent bars, and there are $5$ spaces between adjacent bars, so that uses up $5$ of the $14$ stars, leaving $9$ stars to be distributed however we please amongst the $7$ slots. At this point we have the following arrangement, with $9$ stars left to be placed, and they can go in any of the $7$ slots marked with periods.

```
                    .|*.|*.|*.|*.|*.|.
```

To put it a little differently, between the $9$ remaining stars and the $6$ bars we have a string of $15$ symbols, and the $6$ bars can occupy any $6$ places in that string, so there are $\binom{15}6$ possible strings, each of which corresponds to one of the ways to choose $6$ numbers from the set $\{1,2,\ldots,20\}$, no two of which are consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a line of $14$ stars --the unchosen numbers -- and among the $15$ gaps either in between or outside the stars, choose $6$ of the $15$ for the locations of bars for the six numbers you will be choosing.

Convince yourself that there is an obvious bijection between these star-bar things and the choices for the sets of integers that you want.

The number of them is $C(15,6)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is bijection between every correct setup and tupple
$(a_{0}, a_{1}, ... a_{5})$ where, $a_{0}$ is smallest number you chose and $a_{i>0}$ are differences between subsequent numbers.

So you want to know how many non-negative integer solutions are there for equation:

(1) $a_{0} + a_{1} + ... a_{5} \leq 20 $ with conditions $0 < a_{0}$ and $1 < a_{0<i}$

There are many ways to solve it. ie generating functions, but the easies is this

Substitute for every $0 < i$, $a_{i}$ := $a^{'}_{i} + 1$. Now there is bijection between set of solutions of (1) and (2)

(2) $a_{0} + a^{'}_{1} + ... a^{'}_{5} \leq 15 $ with conditions $0 < a_{i}$

and as you probably can tell this equal to ways of picking any 6 numbers from {1.. 15}